Mi bot de Discord no registra los comandos
Cree un bot de discord en un servidor y este registraba todos los comandos a la perfeccion y cuando voy a ponerlo en otro server no aparecen y me sale el siguiente error:

DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access
at handleErrors (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:727:13)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1128:23)
at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:959:14)
at async _REST.request (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1272:22)
at async C:\Users...\bot.js:36:9 {
requestBody: {
files: undefined,
json: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
},
rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 },
code: 50001,
status: 403,
method: 'PUT',
url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1271441796953800794/guilds/1271149134589595683/commands'
}

Nota: Se que el error aclara que es una falta de permisos pero esto es raro porque tiene todos (applications.command, bot, Administrator).

Resuelvi mi problema buscando en el archivo config.json, resuta que se me olvido cambiar el valor de guildId que es donde se encontraba el id del servidor donde hice las pruebas con el bot y solo tube que cambiarlo por el servidor donde se encuentra ahora.
Ejemplo del codigo que daba problemas:

